# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <CALayerArray: 0x66522e0> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

some times my app crashed by showing  *** Collection  was mutated while being enumerated  . This is occurring in same line of code all the time.please help me on this issue. i stuck on this. the app is crashing at pushing view controller line of my code.but it is not frequent one. my error console

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection     CALayerArray: 0x1030c730 was mutated while being enumerated.
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)'

my code:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 ServiceDetails *service=[[ServiceDetails  alloc] initWithNibName:@"ServiceDetails"   bundle:nil];  
    CompanyListingForm *list=[[CompanyListingForm  alloc]initWithNibName:@"CompanyListingForm" bundle:nil];
[category_company_text resignFirstResponder];
if(viewHoldingTable)
{
    [viewHoldingTable removeFromSuperview];
}
if (category_clicked_flag==0) {
    if (location_or_cat_com==0) {
        NSMutableArray *get=[district_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        locationid=[[get objectAtIndex:0]intValue];
        [location_textfield resignFirstResponder];
        location_textfield.text=[get objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    else
    {
        if (draggingView) {
            [draggingView removeFromSuperview];

        }
        if (viewHoldingTable) {
            [viewHoldingTable removeFromSuperview];
        }


        NSMutableArray *get=[company_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        category_company_text.text=[get objectAtIndex:1];



        service.ida=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[get objectAtIndex:0] intValue]];

        service.idloc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",locationid];



        [self.navigationController pushViewController:service animated:YES];//getting error at this point.

        //[emer release];   
    }
}
else
{
    if (location_or_cat_com==0) {
        NSMutableArray *get=[district_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        locationid=[[get objectAtIndex:0]intValue];
        [location_textfield resignFirstResponder];
        location_textfield.text=[get objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableArray *get=[category_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        category_company_text.text=[get objectAtIndex:1];
        int catid=[[get objectAtIndex:0]intValue];

        list.IDForLoc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",locationid];
        list.IDForCat=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",catid];
        list.companydetails=[get objectAtIndex:1];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:list animated:YES];//getting error at this point.

    } 
}
 [service release];
 [list release];
}
```

Comment: NSMutableArray *getArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[district_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];  try this.

Comment: Thank you for your replay.I tried but still it is there.At the same line.did you see my line of code causing this error? i am getting error at pushing view to navigation controller.

Comment: is district_array NSMutableArray of  NSMutableArray's?

Comment: ya.you are right it is  NSMutableArray of NSMutableArray's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're doing all this stuff to the interface at the same time as you're asking to push a view controller. Try wrapping the `pushViewController` line in a `dispatch_after` block, with a delay of, say, .1 seconds, to give the other changes to the interface time to settle down. Or do it the other way: put the `removeFromSuperview` stuff into a delay. Even better, throw some kind of flag so that the stuff to be removed from the superview is removed later, on `viewWillAppear`. You don't need to do it now; you're about to hide to cover this view with the pushed view controller anyway.

Comment: I tried.still its there.                    viewHoldingTable.hidden=YES;
        
            
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.6* NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
               
                 [self.navigationController pushViewController:company_free animated:YES];
       });

Comment: and one more thing,it is not a frequent error,and its happening after two or more navigation push.and my company_free contain some shadow setting code for my view

Comment: thank you for your solution.i tried it with some modification.its work fine.